# String Array as return value in Java / Android

Tags: android, xml, string, arraylist, sax

I am using a SAX XML Parser to get values out of a XML file that works fine. This is the method in my main activity:

```
public void parseXML() {

    String parsedData = "";

    try {

        Log.w("AndroidParseXMLActivity", "Start");
        /** Handling XML */
        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

        XMLContentHandler myXMLHandler = new XMLContentHandler();
        xr.setContentHandler(myXMLHandler);

        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        try {
            inputStream = assetManager.open("calimero.xml");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
        }
        xr.parse(new InputSource(inputStream)); 

        ArrayList<Datapoint> itemsList = myXMLHandler.getItemsList();
        int datapoint_size = itemsList.size();
        String xml_names[]  = new String [datapoint_size];
        String xml_states[]  = new String [datapoint_size];
        String xml_dptIDs[] = new String [datapoint_size];
        String xml_groupadresses[]  = new String [datapoint_size];
        String xml_mainNumbers[]  = new String [datapoint_size];

        for(int i=0;i<itemsList.size();i++){
            Datapoint item = itemsList.get(i);
            parsedData = parsedData + "----->\n";
            parsedData = parsedData + "Name: " + item.getName() + "\n";
            xml_names[i] = item.getName();
            parsedData = parsedData + "stateBased: " + item.getStateBased() + "\n";
            xml_states[i] = item.getStateBased();
            parsedData = parsedData + "mainNumber: " + item.getMainNumber() + "\n";
            xml_mainNumbers[i] = item.getMainNumber();
            parsedData = parsedData + "dptID: "+ item.getDptID() + "\n";
            xml_dptIDs[i] = item.getDptID();
            parsedData = parsedData + "Groupadress: "+ item.getGroupadress() + "\n";
            xml_groupadresses[i] = item.getGroupadress();
        }
        Log.w("AndroidParseXMLActivity", "Done");
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.w("AndroidParseXMLActivity",e );
    }
    Log.w("AndroidParseXMLActivity", names[0]);
    Log.w("AndroidParseXMLActivity", mainNumbers[2]);
    Log.w("AndroidParseXMLActivity", dptIDs[3]);
    //xmlOutput.setText(parsedData);
}
```

I want to use the values like name, mainNumber and so on outside my method. But I don't get it... I know this are java basic....
Please help me, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use your String array in the whole class you have to define it in the class. Then the variable are avaliable for all functions in your class.

```
    public class Test {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        StringArray testString = new StringArray();
        testString.setArray();
        testString.printArray();
    }

    static private class StringArray{
        String test[];

        public void setArray(){
            test = new String[5];
            for (int i = 0 ; i < test.length; i++){
                test[i] = "test";
            }
        }

        public void printArray(){
            for (int i = 0 ; i < test.length; i++){
                System.out.println(test[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I know that but my string array should have the size of the Array list from the parsed XML file. So i would have to insert the code to implement and start the XML handler also in the variable declaration at the beginning of the class, or?

Comment: You can define it in the class like String name[] = null; and init it in your function like name = new String[datapoint_size];

Comment: Ok that sounds logical, I added the declarations to my code. I have also added the following line to see if it works `Log.i("DataHandler", xml_names[1]);` but now I am getting a null pointer exception. Do you know why?

Comment: Where have you add this line?
How large is your field?

Comment: I have added this line after calling the parseXML method. At the moment there are 5 items created by the for-loop

Comment: Sorry my error. The declaration is only String name[]; You have to remove =null

Comment: First thanks a lot for your help but ther eis a new problem: the getAssets() function inside my method is non-static method... maybe you also know how to solve that...

Comment: I have to declare the field as static because the main function of the class is static. You don't have to declare it as static. I have updatet the answer again.

Comment: I solved the problem. I now use the Datapoint as return value:
`public Datapoint parseXML(){
    
    Datapoint item = null;
    
    for(){
    ...}
    
    return item;
    }`
And in my main function I can then use `item = parseXML();
    String name = item.getName();`

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. I now use the Datapoint as return value:

```
public Datapoint parseXML(){
    Datapoint item = null;

    for(){
        ...
    }

    return item;
}
```

And in my main function I can then use

```
item = parseXML();
String name = item.getName();
```